# Export commands in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

i want to export all the queries in Mongo shell. I want get a file like sql(a file with table,inserts,querys...) but with MongoDB.
Im looking for a command for export that data and i watch a command for export the collection in a file .json, but thats not my idea.
Anyone know anything?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/ Mongo Shell scripts is the closest.
For backup and restoration, another option could be `mongodump` and `mongorestore` https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options one export as JSON, second export as BSON.

For JSON you should use mongoimport and mongoexport binaries. Other way for BSON Mongo provides different binaries they are mongorestore and mongodump.

I'm sharing MongoDB documents, I hope those can help you.

JSON Export
https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongoexport/#connect-to-a-mongodb-instance

BSON Export
https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongodump/#connect-to-a-mongodb-instance

Notice that, BSON is not a human readable content, if you want to check what the exported file has you should try exporting in JSON.